# Creating custom errors hidden in backend response in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, angular-httpclient, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am writing an Angular8 application where the server always gives 200s series answers. All errors from the server side are wrapped inside the `Response object` therefore, I have to create errors from it.

**A typical answer looks like the following**; where the `APP_CODE` property represents health of the answer, `APP_CODE: '001'` means I can read it from result array. If it is `APP_CODE="002"` or `APP_CODE="002"` then there is an error and I should read the error array, etc.

```
{ "input": null, 
  "warningMessages": [],
  "errorMessages": [
     "Please enter at least 3 characters"
  ],
  "numFound": 0,
  "results": [],
  "APP_CODE": "003"
}
```

**Solution Strategy**: There are several strategies that I can go with, but the one that I want is at service level using `map` in `pipe`, generate application specific error then `catchError()`, and pass it to component to decide how to show it whether in a toast, or somehow in the form.

Therefore the code should look like this

```
private handleError(error: MyAppError) {
    console.log('******got you inside handleError', error);
    return throwError(error);
  }

private handleErrorAppCodes(res: any[]) {
    console.log('**** handleErrorAppCodes ****');
    console.log("%o", res);
    if (res["APP_CODE"] === "003") {
    console.log('dataAccess service| Results APP_CODE is', res["APP_CODE"]);
    return throwError(new MyAppError('APP CODE 3:' + res["errorMessages"][0]));
  } 
}
  return res;
}


getMyObject(objectName: string):Observable<any[]> {

let url = 'thisIsAUrl';

return this.http.get<any[]>(url).pipe(
  map(this.handleErrorAppCodes),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

Seems to be a descent error. BUT I get the following error during compile

```
error TS2322: Type 'Observable<any[] | Observable<never>>' is not assignable to type 
'Observable<any[]>'.Type 'any[] | Observable<never>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
Type 'Observable<never>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop,  
push,concat, and 25 more.
```

I also tried `map(res => this.handleErrorAppCodes(res))` the compile error is similar.

Later I tried `map<any[]>(this.handleErrorAppCodes)` but I got

```
error TS2558: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
```

Comment: why somebody gave minus without leaving a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to give to the map operator param the same shape as your handler input's one like this

`map((res: any[]) => this.handleError(res));`

Comment: As you may notices line 3 from bottom, I explained that I put  `I also tried map(res => this.handleErrorAppCodes(res)) the compile error is similar.` in code and it is not working

Comment: and will get the error of `Type 'Observable<any[] | Observable<never>>' is not assignable to type 
'Observable<any[]>'.Type 'any[] | Observable<never>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
Type 'Observable<never>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop,  
push,concat, and 25 more.`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if still relevant, but from what I understood, you are mixing when to return a simple transformation that is handled by rxJS and when to return a proper observable.

Given that you always have a 200 (when things go right or wrong, most likely does not cover when your server goes ka-boom! If the request cannot be processed to shape it like you want, you will most likely get a 500 range error. And those should be covered with a strategy... Most likely pipe a `catchError()` on the top-level.

On the errors that are bundled together with the 200 responses, you probably want to switchMap them into Observables of Data (good old `of(res)`) When response contains no error and `throwError(YourErrorsFromResponse)` otherwise.

This way you are basically deferring ok Vs error responses to be artificially created by the stream. When the switchMap operation concludes, you will have either good data passed normally or error ls being catched and handled as if the initial response was an error itself.

I still think this is probably not a good idea, but if that is what you have to work with (is: 3rd party API, or hard requirement),  then that is how I would approach the problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-catch-error